# Calling a .js file (react) from index.html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im having difficulty to call my js script from my index.html file.
I'm guessing it's because I am not calling it like I should but I can't find the solution online.

Basically I have a index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div id="root"></div>
        <h1>html</h1>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        </body>
 </html>
```

And also a script.js file in the same folder

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

ReactDOM.render(

    <h1>This is my script</h1>

);
```

My goal here is to run my js file which will then run my entire react app. Thanks a lot for any help you can give me.

(New to React, trying to run my app locally without having to use node.js)

Comment: If it can help, the error shown is:

    "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"

Comment: So you want to run the react code in pure javascript?

Comment: No I dumbed down the code to try to isolate the error I was having. The entire app is gonna use react-redux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to use the Babel transpiler to translate from ES6 to a version of javascript your browser understands. That's the standard way of using ES6 features in the browser.

Many projects use Babel as part of their build pipeline, although you can also do the translation at runtime. The official React documentation uses [Babel Standalone](https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone) in their "Hello world" examples.

Comment: Yeah I saw a solution that used babel earlier but it didn't work on my first try so I moved on. You're saying I need to install (npm install --save-dev babel-preset-env), then use it in my script code and it should work on all browsers?

Comment: I'm not sure about that particular library (I usually use Webpack). I added a link to the in-browser version that the official React docs use in their examples. (It compiles at runtime, so it's too slow for production code).

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I'll comment back with my result !

Answer (score 2):

Browsers don't support import feature.

I don't think it's posible to develop a modern app without node. If it's posible it won't be easier.

Comment: This is only partially correct. See my answer for more details.

Comment: @speckledcarp yeah. that's true. It was me who set first vote to your answer, but it's terrible idea to write react app in one file without node and other features.

Comment: That's true, but it's the only way I've found of running my app locally (client-side only) without having to start a server or anything. If you guys have any other idea on how to do that, I'm always open to hearing them !

Comment: @petithomme - Stanislav brings up a good point. How come you only want it to execute client side?

Comment: The users that are going to use the app have to use it locally so they don't have to start a server or anything. They can do their thing locally and then their actions will update/get from the API. It's the best solution that we've found for now, because when we were using server also, we experienced authentication problems so making it only client-side was a good workaround.

Comment: @petithomme node js is used only for development then you get compiled static files!

Comment: So I just develop my app using node.js and then when it's all done I compile it all and the user has it directly on his computer without needing to start a server?

Comment: @petithomme exactly!

Comment: For those like me that didn't really understand at first, you can use **node.js** on the dev side. When you're done making your web app, you can just 
`npm run build`
in your terminal. It will automatically create a new folder with a **index.html** file where you can start your app from.
PS: React already has **babel** installed so you don't have to install it yourself.